# How do I specify the edition to use when compiling code using rustc?

Tags: rust

I want to use `rustc` to compile a project written in Rust 2018 but I don't know how to switch the compiler from the default edition. The manpage for `rustc` mentions nothing about editions and the [builtin attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html) don't seem to contain anything relevant either. I'm using the Debian version of rustc (1.58.1) which was built earlier this year so it should support all three editions.

What do I need to do to get `rustc` to treat my code as Rust '18?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on Debian, the manual page that ships with Rust is incomplete. Passing `--help` to `rustc` shows that the relavent flag to set is `--edition`:

```
Usage: rustc [OPTIONS] INPUT

Options:
    -h, --help          Display this message
        --cfg SPEC      Configure the compilation environment
[...]
        --edition 2015|2018|2021
                        Specify which edition of the compiler to use when
                        compiling code.
```